# Rotate bottle image in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, 3d

I'm looking a way to rotate the bottle image in HTML, to achive [a similar effect](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/41552017083231.562b5dc92b322.gif). The idea is to show entire label, not just a fraction of it.

[image]

Just masking the label on top of bottle is probably not a good option, as it needs to be "3d" to look natural.

Comment: Use the CSS3 transform property?

Comment: @Atrix Either that or a spritesheet animated by Javascript, perhaps via: http://spritespin.ginie.eu/

Comment: Maybe this one could give you some ideas - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781634/rotating-globe-in-css/27781670#27781670. I don't think it is a dupe though.

Answer (score 1):

Two options :

First is to get this gif (if you already have gif or png sequence)
 make sequence of animation (If you have 3d project you can also generate images from 3d software). Then use some canvas2d framework and preview this sequence .

- You can do it also with classic html tags and timers .

Secund is use three.js or similar webgl engines to render this obj.
 Than it is a simple rotation in 3d space . Blender is freeware use it. Import object (obj) intro blender . Goto edit mode and select faces for botle textures - press space type "unwrap" , insert you image . Export from blender to obj . See how to load obj with three.js with textures .

Both projects are simple and they can works on all devices (desktops/mobiles device).

If you wanna use my library (canvas2d) for animation see :

[Visual js game engine](https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js)

Take a look animation class :

[Animation class](https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js/src/bdb64535b407fdcea5ba70bf30b8c22604a3e09b/project/program_instance/lib/draw_functions/animation.js?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

reference :

Gif file split to frame by frame

http://ezgif.com/split